# how to register XML schemas in Oracle

Tags: oracle, xsd

I have a bunch of schemas that I validated using XMLSpy.

I would like to register them in Oracle. How does one go about this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in DBMS_XMLSCHEMA package.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb05sto.htm#i1031977).